# How do I use Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I would like to know how do i use Access-Control-Allow-Origin ?

In fact, i try to load xml data from a distant file into a html (into a ) but i have this mistake during the request :

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.mysite.net/douce/bonsplans.xml. Origin http://mysite.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Thanks for your reply

---

Mmmm, ok, so i think that is not possible for me to use this method. Here is my source code :

mypage.html :

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<title>monsite</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
        function init(){
        loadXMLDoc('http://www.monsite.net/bonsplans.xml');
        }
</SCRIPT>

</head>

<body onload="init();" onunload="clear();">

<div id="bonplans" class="panel4" title="Bons plans">
        <p style="text-align:left;"><font color="#4e559c" size="3px"><b>Dernières minutes :</b></font></p>
        <div id="writeDernieresMinutes"></div>
        <p style="text-align:left;"><font color="#4e559c" size="3px"><b>Offres permanentes :</b></font></p>
        <div id="writeOffresPermanentes"></div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the script.js file :

```
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)

 {
    dernieresminutes="";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("DERNIEREMINUTE");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE");
        {
        try
          {
          dernieresminutes=dernieresminutes + "<fieldset><legend><font color='#4e559c' size='2px'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</font></legend>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          dernieresminutes=dernieresminutes + "<p>erreur*</p>";
          }
        }
        xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT");
        {
        try
          {
          dernieresminutes=dernieresminutes + "<div class=\"row\"><font color='blue' size='3px'><center>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</center></font>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          dernieresminutes=dernieresminutes + "<p>erreur*</p>";
          }
        }
        dernieresminutes=dernieresminutes + "</font></div></fieldset>";
      }
    document.getElementById('writeDernieresMinutes').innerHTML=dernieresminutes;
  } 



  {
    OffresPermanentes="";
    x=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("OFFREPERMANENTE");
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
      {
      xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITRE");
        {
        try
          {
          OffresPermanentes=OffresPermanentes + "<fieldset><legend><font color='#4e559c' size='2px'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</font></legend>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          OffresPermanentes=OffresPermanentes + "<p>erreur*</p>";
          }
        }
        xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("CONTENT");
        {
        try
          {
          OffresPermanentes=OffresPermanentes + "<div class=\"row\"><font color='blue' size='3px'><center>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</center></font>";
          }
        catch (er)
          {
          OffresPermanentes=OffresPermanentes + "<p>erreur*</p>";
          }
        }
        OffresPermanentes=OffresPermanentes + "</font></div></fieldset>";
      }
    document.getElementById('writeOffresPermanentes').innerHTML=OffresPermanentes;
  }




}
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}



function getXhr(){
    var xhr = null; 
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox et autres
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){ // Internet Explorer 
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    else { // XMLHttpRequest non supporté par le navigateur 
        alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest..."); 
        xhr = false; 
    } 
    return xhr
}
```

So i fact, during the loading of mapage.html, the script must load the xml file from a distant source, parse it and write the content into the .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the response from mysite.net it would have to include a header with:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: [domain from where you're calling]`

(So, if you're thissite.com, it would be `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: thissite.com`)

or

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (this would allow from all).

If you don't run mysite.net then there is no way to do this and you'll have to come with alternate means to obtain this data.  (Unless you can get them to supply the data in JSONP, your best bet is to write server side code to retrieve it that runs on the same domain as the HTML file you want to present it in, and then use an XHR to obtain that data.)

If you need help adding headers to server responses, we need to know what HTTP server you're using and if you're using any sort of scripting language in conjunction with that.

Comment: Mozilla has some decent documentation on Cross Site XHR, you should check it out: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/

Comment: I have had some notes into my post

Comment: @user1076026 there is no way to do this unless you can get the owner of the other site to modify their server to add that request header. It's a security feature in the web that prevents random sites from know whether you're logged into Facebook or gmail or something else.

Comment: If you need help writing a server side proxy for this data, we'd be glad to help with that, but that's an entirely different question an should be posted separately :)

Comment: In fact, i am the owner of the other site, but i don't know where i must had this line. The file is stored in a web space.

Comment: What server do you use? Is it a shared host? Do you have access to php, python, ruby, etc?

Comment: Yes, i think i can have access to php files. Where i can include header? In a php file?

Comment: @user1076026 if you serve your XML file via a PHP script, you can add headers to your response: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php  you should ask another question since this comment chain is out of control :)

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand. I will try to explain better. I have an html page wich contain the call to the loadXMLDoc function. This funtion is located in the script.js file. In this script, i use XmlHttpResquest to establish the connection and to parse the xml file. Then, i wrote into the <div> the result in my page.html. The XML file is stored into a web space into an httpdocs folder. In this web space i don't have any php file. Maybe, these file are hidden, i can ask to my host..